# Google App Script: code changing my date format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
function deleteDuplicateRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  data = data.map(row => row.join(";"));
  const uniqueRows = [... new Set(data)].filter(String)
  const newData = uniqueRows.map(row => row.split(";"));
  const newLastRow = newData.length;
  const newLastCol = newData[0].length;
  ss.clearContents();
  ss.getRange(1, 1, newLastRow, newLastCol).setValues(newData)
}
```

Before

[image]

After (Current result)

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. What are your provided images? And, can I ask you about the details of the relationship between your images and your script? And, what are your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I am using this code to delete duplicate data. I have date column with the format "2/03/2023". when i run this code it deletes the duplicate data but changes my date format from "2/03/2023" to "Fri Nov 03 2023 00:00:00 GMT+1030 (Australian Central Daylight Time)" but i dont want that. I want my date format to stay dd/mm/yy-"2/03/2023". like this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a Spreadsheet including the date objects in cells "H2:H".
- You want to remove duplicate rows by comparing all columns.
- In your current issue, when your showing script is run, the date format is changed although the duplicate values are removed.
- You want to achieve your goal by keeping the date format.

In this case, how about the following modifications?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your showing script is modified.

```js
function deleteDuplicateRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let data = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); // <--- Modiifed
  data = data.map(row => row.join(";"));
  const uniqueRows = [... new Set(data)].filter(String);
  const newData = uniqueRows.map(row => row.split(";"));
  const newLastRow = newData.length; const newLastCol = newData[0].length;
  ss.clearContents();
  ss.getRange(1, 1, newLastRow, newLastCol).setValues(newData);
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, I proposed another approach to achieving your goal.

```js
function deleteDuplicateRows() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().removeDuplicates();
}
```

#### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [removeDuplicates()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removeduplicates)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, It is not working now also it is removing all the data!

Comment: @TimeCard Admin Thank you for replying. About `Hi Tanaike, It is not working now also it is removing all the data!`, I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, I think that it is required to correctly replicate your situation. So, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet including my proposed script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Because, when I tested my scripts using a sample sheet, no issue occurred. I deeply apologize for this situation.